# ASP.NET Core Web API cannot return JSON formatted object after a call to `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a web API `OnGet()` that takes a `ZapScan` parameter as its input and returns it as JSON or XML.

```
[HttpGet, FormatFilter]
public ActionResult<ZapScan> OnGet([FromQuery] ZapScan scan)
{
   return Ok(scan); // return JSON/XML representation of "scan" argument
}
```

However, if the provided `ZapScan` argument contains invalid values, then I would like to return a  500 status-code, a custom error message, and the `ZapScan` object formatted as JSON/XML:

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
await HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid request.");
... 
return scan;
```

The problem is that after a call to `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()` then `return scan;` has no effect - i.e. `scan` is not returned as JSON in the response together with the `"Invalid request."` error message.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, scan);

Comment: As with any Request to an API, once the server returns, that's it, no more responses.

This is an API request essentially. If I were you, I would return an object with the result, and a custom status code or Boolean to indicate if it was successful or not. Or you can return the status code, and serialise your `scan` to the message and deserialise it on your client.

Comment: Once you manually write to the response, you're done. It all has to be manual from there.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - have you read that from the documentation? Would you provide a small example, where I also return the `scan` object using `WriteAsync()`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's input validation error, standard way would be to return:

```cs
ModelState.AddModelError("", "ZapScan invalid");

return new BadRequestObjectResult(new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState));
```

This would return 400 Bad Request error with your error response as JSON. You don't have to return `scan` object to the user, because user has sent it, he knows the value already.

You can automate this process if you put `ApiControllerAttribute` on your `Controller` and use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` validation attributes on your `ZapScan` class properties (`Required`, `MaxLength`, etc...). You can read more about this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: isn't the same with return BadRequest(ModelState)

Comment: @SilentTremor Errors will be nested in example with `ValidationProblemDetails` in `errors` property in standard format (RFC 7807). More, your example BadRequest(ModelState) would just return 400, without body. It stopped working at some point. Based on what documentation says, I assume at version 2.2

Comment: hmm, really? I have to review some migrated api's.

Comment: @SilentTremor Yes. Check the documentation. Another reason to fix it, if you use `ApiControllerAttribute` it would return new "nested" format (`ValidationProblemDetails`) . You want your manually created bad response and automated one, triggered by `ApiControllerAttribute` to have same format. I noticed on ASP.NET Core 3.0 that things are working differently.